# Debian set google-chrome as gnome-www-browser

Tags: linux, browser, debian, package-management, dependencies

I've recently set up Debian 6.0.6 and want to install google-chrome as the default web browser.
The problem is that I can't remove others browsers (Iceweasel particularly) because there is a `gnome-core` package that depends on it:

```
    --\ Depends (1)
iB    gnome-core 1:2.30+7
  --\ Versions of gnome-www-browser (6)
p    kazehakase 0.5.8-4
p    galeon 2.0.7-2.1+b1
p    epiphany-browser 2.30.6-1
pp   iceweasel 3.5.16-17
ip   iceweasel 3.5.16-20
p    chromium-browser 6.0.472.63~r59945-5+squeeze6
```

Is there any mean to remove Iceweasel and set up google-chrome instead of it?
I could install Chromium but I would rather prefer google-chrome.

UPD: the same problem emerges when I try to replace Evolution mail client with Icedove.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set `google-chrome` as your default browser. Open `google-chrome` and go to *Settings* and check the box under *Default Browser*. Another way to do this in GNOME 2 is by going to *System* -> *Preferences* -> *Preferred Applications* and under the *Internet* tab, choosing `google-chrome` from the list. Or if you prefer doing this from the command line:

```
# update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Now you should be able to remove Iceweasel and Epiphany.

Comment: This would not work. The gnome-core package depends on having a package installed which provides the gnome-www-browser virtual package. Changing alternatives or the default Gnome browser has no effect on package dependencies.